# dynamic sql decode not taking the null value

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I am trying to run the below procedure,the DBMS_OUTPUT of the code does not take Null value in the Decode function i.e if i run the anonymous block of the procedure and pass NULL in p_code it gives an error missing expression and shows blank at the position of P_code.

```
create or replace 
    PROCEDURE PROC_ORDER_VIOLATION_new_1(
        P_TYPE          NUMBER,
        P_CODE          VARCHAR2,
        REQUEST_ID IN VARCHAR2,
        USER_ID    IN VARCHAR2,
        V_OUT OUT VARCHAR2 )
    IS
    Begin

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE '||REQUEST_ID|| ' AS SELECT * FROM GTT_ORDER_VIOLATION_TAB_NEW WHERE 1=2';

    --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
    dbms_output.put_line('INSERT
      INTO '||REQUEST_ID||
        ' (
          O_ID,
          PARTNER_TYPE_NAME,
          COMPANY_NAME,
          PARTNER_CODE,
          PO_NUMBER,
          PO_STATUS,
          PO_SUBMIT_DATE,
          PO_APPROVAL_DATE,
          ORDERING_RATIO_FLAG
        )'||
      ' SELECT O.ID,
        pt.name,
        PP.COMPANY_NAME,
        PP.CODE,
        O.ORDER_NUMBER,
        O.STATUS,
        O.SUBMIT_DATE,
        O.APPROVAL_DATE,
        O.ORDERING_RATIO_FLAG '||
       'FROM ORDERS O,
        PARTNERPROFILE PP,partnertype pt '||
      'WHERE PP.TYPE_ID                   ='||P_TYPE||
      ' AND O.ORDERING_RATIO_FLAG          ='||P_FLAG||
      ' AND PP.ID                          =O.TO_PARTNER_ID
      and pt.id=pp.type_id 
      AND DECODE(P_CODE,NULL,''1'',PP.CODE)= DECODE(P_CODE,NULL,''1'',P_CODE)');--here the dbms_output gives nothing at place of p_code
    end;
```

Comment: Stop creating tables on the fly. You will have problems with performance and design.

Comment: You don't have a `P_FLAG` argument so this won't compile anyway. If that's added it executes OK and displays the output, not the error you said. If you try with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` then you'd get ORA-00904 invalid identifier, as `P_CODE` in the decodes is out of scope - it won't see the procedure argument value in that dynamic SQL string. Showing the actual code that generates your actual error would help. (Really not sure why you'd want to use dynamic SQL for this, creating tables on the fly is a bad idea, and you already appear to have GTTs so should know how those work.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments: @ Zaratustra well creation of dynamic tables is imporatant as the request would be threaded instead of being called sequentially.

Comment: @ Alex Poole: P_Flag would be required later. For a time being i have shared only what i need to test with for a time being. Yes p_flag would give the exception. A user can request for a particular procedure more than once so if he sends the multiple requests,all of them would be specific to his/her session. therefore, the requirement says request should not be dependent on each other and should run simultaneously i.e, one procedure should run simultaneously if many requests are there. hope i m clear

Comment: also I am dropping the tables created at the end of procedure. May be i haven't incoporated that in this but that is a part of procedure.

Comment: Um, not really. Your code has `' AND O.ORDERING_RATIO_FLAG          ='||P_FLAG||`, but P_FLAG isn't defined anywhere. Don't understand your dynamic-table comment, why wouldn't a GTT work here, as the data in those is private to the session? Anyway, the code you posted doesn't give the error you asked about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you showed doesn't produce the error you said; with the missing `P_FLAG` parameter ignored the `dbms_output` works, and `execute immediate` gets ORA-00904 as `p_code` is out of scope. So I deduce that you actually got the ORA-00936 missing expression when you executed the code and concatenated the `p_code` value, like:

```
AND DECODE('||P_CODE||',NULL,''1'',PP.CODE)= DECODE('||P_CODE||',NULL,''1'','||P_CODE||')';
```

When `p_code` is null that would turn into:

```
AND DECODE(,NULL,'1',PP.CODE)= DECODE(,NULL,'1',)
```

... hence the error.

So you need to interpret the `p_code` in the string generation:

```
AND '|| CASE WHEN P_CODE IS NULL THEN '''1''' ELSE 'PP.CODE' END ||
  '='''||NVL(P_CODE, 1)||'''';
```

When `p_code` is null the generated code gets:

```
AND '1'='1'
```

When `p_code` is not null, passing say `SOME_VALUE`, the generated code gets:

```
AND PP.CODE='SOME_VALUE'
```

Although I'd probably leave out the whole clause when `p_code` is null, rather than having the redundant tautology.